# Can a program contain unbound variables if they will not be evaluated?

Tags: scheme

Consider the following program, where `foo` and `bar` have not been defined.

```lisp
(define (f)
  foo)

(if #t
    (display "Hello!")
    bar)
```

Is this a valid Scheme program? Are Scheme programs allowed to have unbound variables as long as those variables are never evaluated?

Answer (score 1):

No:

"It is a syntax violation to reference an unbound variable" ([r6rs report](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-12.html#node_sec_9.1) 9.1)

"It is an error to reference an unbound variable." ([r7rs report](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) 4.1.1)

The question code may be evaluated by a Scheme implementation, but is not a Scheme *program*,
and if included in a program the implementation should signal an error:

```
$ scheme

> (if #t (display "Hello!") bar)
Hello!

> (top-level-program (import (rnrs))
      (if #t (display "Hello!") bar))
Exception: attempt to reference unbound identifier bar
>
```

##### Notes

`(top-level-program )` is a Chez Scheme extension, and can be used to enter a Scheme program interactively.

Extracts from r6rs report related to the meanings of **Scheme program**, **variable**, and **unbound**
(*italic* emphasis in original, **bold** added):

> ##### 5.1 Programs and libraries
>
> A **Scheme program** consists of a *top-level program* together with a set of libraries
>
> ##### 5.2 Variables, keywords, and regions
>
> ... An identifier that names a location is called a ***variable*** and is said to be *bound* to that location ...
> **Every mention** of an identifier refers to the binding of the identifier that establishes the innermost
> of the regions containing the use. ...
> If there is no binding for the identifier, it is said to be ***unbound***.
>
> ##### 9.1. Primitive expression types / Variable references
>
> An expression consisting of a variable (section 5.2) is a variable reference ...
> It is a **syntax violation** to reference an unbound variable.
>
> ##### 5.5. Syntax violations
>
> ... implementations **must** detect violations of the syntax. A *syntax violation* is an error with respect to
> the syntax of library bodies, top-level bodies ...
> If a top-level or library form in a program is not syntactically correct, then ...
> **execution of that top-level program or library must not be allowed to begin**.

So a Scheme program can contain an unbound variable, but a standard-compliant implementation must not start evaluating
the program, even if evaluation of the variable could never be attempted.

Comment: the OP said ***as long as those variables are never evaluated***

Comment: (appended Notes section to original answer)

Comment: I think that this is basically correct. The distinction between a _Scheme program_ and _evaluating a series of forms in the REPL_ is good to make; OP doesn't seem to make this distinction. Note that R7RS has relevant language in **5.7 The REPL**: "_Implementations may provide an initial REPL environment which behaves as if all possible variables are bound to locations, most of which contain unspecified values._"

Comment: R6RS is silent on interactive environments, but I suspect that most implementations would allow this since it is fine to introduce unbound variables which are later bound in subsequent expressions so long as the variables are not _evaluated_ before being bound.

Answer (score 1):

No, but yes, but no...

Interpreting the terms *Scheme program*, *unbound*, and *variable* as used in recent
Scheme reports, it seems that the answer is no (see my other answer for references).

But this depends on one more assumption about the sample code - that `if` has its usual meaning
as the *syntactic keyword* described in the language defining reports.

Because identifiers in Scheme programs can shadow keywords, this is a valid
Scheme program in which `bar` appears to be unbound:

```
(import (rnrs))
(let-syntax ([if (syntax-rules ()
      [(if e1 e2 _) (if e1 e2)])])
  (if #t
      (display "Hello!")
      bar))
```

So:

```
$ scheme
> (top-level-program (import (rnrs))
  (let-syntax ([if (syntax-rules ()
        [(if e1 e2 _) (if e1 e2)])])
    (if #t
        (display "Hello!")
        bar)
    (if #f
        (display "Hello!")
        bar)))
Hello!
>
```